# How do I set the default value of a column to today's date?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I'm currently working on a small project in which I need to insert some data into database tables. What I want to do is to set the default value of a certain column to today's date, but **only to today's date**.

Is this even possible? I already tried the datatypes **DATETIME** and **TIME** and its functions **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()** and **TIMESTAMP()** to set their value. Problem is that I **only** want to have **the today's date** in my column, not the date and the time. Does anyone know if that's possible?

Here an example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Bestellung(
BestellNr MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Bestelldatum DATE DEFAULT ??? NOT NULL,
FahrerID TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
KundenNr SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(FahrerID) REFERENCES
Fahrer(FahrerID) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(KundenNr) REFERENCES
Kunde(KundenNr) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
PRIMARY KEY(BestellNr),
INDEX(Bestelldatum)
)
```

Comment: You can't set the default value of a `DATE` column. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html

Comment: @Barmar: Wow, what a stupid restriction.

Comment: @dnoeth MySQL has lots of stupid restrictions, like not being able to refer to the same temporary table twice in a query, not allowing subqueries in views, not allowing `LIMIT` in subqueries used in `WHERE-IN`.

Comment: @dnoeth Until recently you couldn't have a default value on more than one `TIMESTAMP` column in a table.

Comment: What version of MySQL/MariaDB are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySL you could use the function CURDATE() to retun only the date as YYYY-MM-DD.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: You can't use it in the `DEFAULT` option of `CREATE TABLE`

Comment: MariaDB 10.2.1 allows `DEFAULT(expression)`.  See [Create table](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/create-table/) .